# Displaying array properties in Safari's console

Tags: javascript, safari, console.log

Given the following snippet:

```js
const myArray = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
myArray.someProperty = "foobar";
console.log(myArray)
```

In Safari, it will display only this:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"] (3)
```

In other browsers, like Chrome and Firefox, it will display the `someProperty` property, along with native properties like `length`:

```
Array(3)
  0: "foo"
  1: "bar"
  2: "baz"
  someProperty: "foobar"
  length: 3
```

It's worth mentioning that things like `console.dir`, `console.table` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray))` won't work for displaying such properties.

Is there any workaround for this limitation in Safari? Obviously I could just do `console.log(myArray.someProperty)`, but my main goal is **checking** what properties the array have (I'm not the one creating the array, it's being created by a JS library), so those properties are unknown to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to convert it to Object first

```
console.log(Object.assign({}, myArray))
```

It will show all of your array properties

Comment: That's a clever solution. I like the fact that, not being enumerable, `Array.length` is not included in the object.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58579628/12273078) I can even strip the numeric keys (which are the common array content) and log only the array's properties, if any:

```js
const myArray = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
myArray.someProperty = "foobar";
myArray.someOtherProperty = "barbaz";

logArrayProperties(myArray)

function logArrayProperties(arr) {
  Object.entries(Object.assign({}, arr)).forEach(row => {
    if (isNaN(row[0])) console.log(row[0] + ": " + row[1])
  });
};
```

Comment: It seem like a feature of Safari, an Array basically can not had a key as a String, it just need a number. So if you add new property as a Number, in will shown on console.log, if you add as String, it will not. Try this, very fun

const myArray = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
myArray.someProperty = "foobar";
console.log(myArray);
myArray[6] = "Test";
console.log(myArray);
myArray["test"] = "Test";
console.log(myArray);